# firefox - Unable to login via smart card pin on company websites

Tags: firefox, tpm, smartcard

I'm not able to login via smart card PIN on enterprise websites. This works in other browsers Chrome/Brave/Edge etc.

```
Secure connection failed

A PKCS #11 module returned CKG_GENERAL_ERROR, indicating that an unrecoverable error has occurred.

Error code: SEC_ERROR_PKCS11_GENERAL_ERROR
```

I'm using TPM 2.0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step 1

Install OpenSC, which is an open source driver for smart card pin which works with firefox.
Install the Windows MSI 64 bit installer.
https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/releases/tag/0.22.0

Step 2

Follow the instructions here, to add the driver to firefox and start using.

Installing OpenSC PKCS#11 Module in Firefox, Step by Step · OpenSC/OpenSC Wiki · GitHub
https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Installing-OpenSC-PKCS%2311-Module-in-Firefox,-Step-by-Step

This is what it looks like when the driver is loaded into firefox,
[image]

Step 3

Restart the browser
and try to login again to your company site.

You will now get a prompt to input your PIN.

Comment: honestly this should be built in, as every enterprise user would be hit by this.

Comment: It's worth noting that I have found latest Firefox ESR (102.5) is actually better _without_ OpenSC. I previously had OpenSC installed but have always had issues with repeated PIN prompts, being unable to choose which smart card to use (e.g. when 1 inserted + 1 virtual in TPM) etc. but since uninstalling OpenSC it is now working well natively. If using a smartcard-on-a-YubiKey also install https://www.yubico.com/support/download/smart-card-drivers-tools/

Answer (score 0):

It's not useful to install OpenSC.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYdmG.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPfBp.jpg

> The Path must be : C:\Windows\System32\cardos11_64.dll
> Test using "connexion" button.

I'm using this all days with my entreprize PKI card.

Comment: not sure what you mean, do you mean add a driver pointing to "cardos11_64.dll"?